# save vector<geometry_msgs::Point> to a file

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I need to save vector of geometry_msgs::Point to a file because I need to reuse it in a future. I have already done some research (e.g. tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469531/reading-and-writing-c-vector-to-a-file) but nothing worked...any ideas? Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance, JP

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142731/save-vector%3Cgeometry_msgs::point%3E-to-a-file/) by [jpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/12791/jpo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-21**:
Do you need to write that from code? ROS tools like rosbag or rostopic echo enable you to dump messages to files easily. There is also the rosbag api.

**Comment by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on 2014-03-21**:
If u want i can give u a cpp file that saves subsribed topic to CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with @dornhege. I would first try to use rosbag (maybe create a custom message with a list of points, or store all points as messages on a single topic). Alternatively, you can directly write rosbags from your program using the rosbag API [1,2]. If that doesn't suit you either, you can directly serialize the individual messages using the message serialization facilities [3]. Lastly, you are always free to just write your own specialized serialization. After all, a Point message is just 3 floats.

[1] http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API

[2] http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook

[3] http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1